# How to access the files in this folder from add-on?

Tags: path, firefox-addon

I'm making bootstrapped add-on, and I can't figure out how to access the images of default16.png etc that are located in this folder in mxr: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/branding/official/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to [search MXR for the string](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=default16.png)

Now, those `.nm` files look interesting because they define how stuff will be packaged (so what jar these will be placed in and the `chrome.manifest`).

Let's check out http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/branding/official/content/jar.mn:

```
% content branding %content/branding/ contentaccessible=yes
...
content/branding/icon16.png                    (../default16.png)
```

OK, so looks like there is a `branding` package where the icon will be in `content/icon16.png`
The corresponding URI will be `chrome://branding/content/icon16.png`.

Opening `chrome://branding/content/icon16.png` in the browser yields the correct result.

Note that what branding (`official`, `aurora`, `nightly`) is used is defined a build-time, so only one of these directories will be packaged (`MOZ_BRANDING_DIRECTORY` in the build system, and the `--enable-official-branding` and/or `--enable-branding-dir=` configure options), and the branding `package` will always point to what is packaged.

So there is no real way to access `official` specificly, as it might not even be packaged at all (in Aurora, Nightly).

Comment: Thanks man I finally figured out how I can figure this out myself thanks to your explanation :)